# Sequelize, how structuring return value inside single object

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, sequelize.js, fastify

Sorry for my bad English. I have used fastify for my javascript framework and Postgresql as my database and sequelize as my ORM. But problem occured when i have multiple models.

This is my Code :

```
    // Extract Db
    const { student} = this.models
    return student.findById(id, {
        include: [
            { all: true },
        ],
        limit: 1,
    })
```

The result is :

```
// Result
{
    id: 1,
    name: "my beastiful name",
    class: "...",
    ...

    // School Object
    school: {
        id: 23,
        name: "My School name",
        ...
    }
}
```

But what i want is :

```
// Result
{
    // Student Object
    student: {
        id: 1,
        name: "my beastiful name",
        class: "...",
        ...
    },

    // School Object
    school: {
        id: 23,
        name: "My School name",
        ...
    }
}
```

Should i use multiple "find" to achive this result.

Comment: Is your school table separate then student table ?

Comment: y. school table separate with student table. but associated. By the way, school and student table is just an alias or example.

Comment: In that case you will get the school object in side the student is it okay for you ?